# throw new MongooseError('Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback'); MongooseError: Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

i am trying to register and authenticate user using passport.
registration form is working fine

```
throw new MongooseError('Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback');
          ^

MongooseError: Query.prototype.exec() no longer accepts a callback
    at Function.schema.statics.findByUsername (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:298:13)   
    at C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport-local-mongoose\index.js:218:12
    at pass (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:354:9)
    at Authenticator.deserializeUser (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:359:5)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:61:10)
    at attempt (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:369:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:370:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\ANKUSH\OneDrive\Desktop\project_IWT\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
```

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
// const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");
// const dotenv = require("dotenv");
// const md5 = require("md5");
// const saltround = 2;

const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({

    extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
    secret:"Our Little Secret",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/iwtDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });

mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);


const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    ids:String,
    password:String,
    email:String,
    age:String,
    gender:String,
    address:String,
    branch:String,
    skill:String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


// dotenv.config();

// var secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

// UserSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret , encryptedFields:['password']});

const User = new mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("main");
})

app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("login", {
        wrongEmail: "",
        wrongPassword: ""
    });
});

app.get("/form", function (req, res) {
    res.render("form");
});

app.get("/main",function(req,res){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
    {
        res.render("main");
    }
    else
    {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});

app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.logout(function(err){res.redirect("/")});
    
})
app.post("/form", function (req, res) {
   User.register({username:req.body.username,ids:req.body.ids,email:req.body.email,age:req.body.age,gender:req.body.gender,  address:req.body.gender,branch:req.body.branch,skill:req.body.skill},req.body.password,function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/form");
    }
    else
    {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
            res.redirect("/main");
        });
    }
   })
});
app.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    const user = new User({
      
        username:req.body.username,
        name:req.body.name,
        password:req.body.password
    });

    req.login(user, function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            });
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Server started on port 3000")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Callback functions have been deprecated from now onwards, you need to update your code to use async operations with mongoose 7 instead of callbacks. Here are the change patterns:

Change deserializer **from:**

```
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

**to:**

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    return done(null, await User.findById(id));
  } catch(error) {
    return done(error);
  } 
});
```

If you are using other operations like user model lookups, then you would need to change them like the following **from:**

```
User.findone(criteria, function(err, models){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else {
    console.log(models);
  }
});
```

**to:**

```
User.findone(criteria)
.then(function (models) {
  console.log(models);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and finally I fixed it using vanilla Passport JS instead of using passport-local-mongoose because after recent Mongoose 7 update they removed callback support for a lot of functions and passport-local-mongoose is based on mongoose so it will not work until they update the module. So you can either use the old version of Mongoose or use Passport JS way (it is long though).

Here is my code for app.js file without using passport-local-mongoose:

```
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
const ejs=require("ejs")
const mongoose=require("mongoose")
const bcrypt=require("bcrypt")
const session=require("express-session")
const passport=require("passport")
const LocalStrategy=require("passport-local").Strategy;
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))  //Not using bodyParser, using Express in-built body parser instead
app.set("view engine","ejs")
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.use(session({
    secret:"Justarandomstring.",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB")
const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    username : String,
    password : String
})

const User=new mongoose.model("User",userSchema)

//Creating Local Strategy. passport-local-mongoose 3 lines of code for Strategy, 
//Serialiazation, Deserialization not working due to recent changes in Mongoose 7

passport.use(new LocalStrategy((username,password,done)=>{  //done is a callback function
    try{
        User.findOne({username:username}).then(user=>{
            if (!user){
                return done(null,false, {message:"Incorrect Username"})
            }
 //using bcrypt to encrypt passoword in register post route and compare function in login post round. 
 //login post route will check here during authentication so need to use compare here  
            bcrypt.compare(password,user.password,function(err,result){ 
                if (err){
                    return done(err)
                }

                if (result) {
                    return done(null,user)
                }
                else {
                    return done (null,false, {message:"Incorrect Password"})
                }
            })

        })
    }
    catch (err){
            return done(err)
    }

}))
//serialize user
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  
//deserialize user  
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("Deserializing User")
    try {
        User.findById(id).then(user=>{
            done(null,user);
        })
    }
    catch (err){
        done(err);
    }
  });


//get routes
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home")
})

app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login")
})

app.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register")
})

app.get("/secrets",function(req,res){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("secrets")
    }
    else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }
})

app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.logout(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.redirect("/");
    });
    
})

//post routes
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,function(err,hash){  //10 is SaltRounds
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        const user= new User ({
            username:req.body.username,
            password:hash
        })
        user.save()

        passport.authenticate('local')(req,res,()=>{res.redirect("/secrets")}) 
    })
})   
    


app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect:"/secrets", failureRedirect: '/login' }));

//listen
app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log("Server Running on Port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem my suggestion is to just install previous version by using
command -- > npm install mongoose6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in my project.
I saw that new version of mongoose callback functionality is not available. If use still want to use that than my recomendation is use   "mongoose": "^6.10.0" version of mongoose.
u can install this using

```
npm i mongoose@6.10.4
```